# How to sort a character array of ascii characters in linear time and constant space

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

This is an interview question I.

```
A string of ascii characters, in sorted order of their ascii values. You can overwrite the existing array 

Aim for linear time and constant additional space

Use the fact that ascii has only 256 unique characters
```

I can accomplish linear time complexity by incrementing the count of the cell, to cell[i]+256, and then do a (cell[i]/256)+1, to get the count. And then maybe, print out the string. But that would still be `O(n)` space, since I cannot save the output in the same array as input.

Also, the method prototype given is,

```
public String sortCharacters(String str)
{

}
```

Since strings are immutable in Java, isn't this problem impossible to solve?

Comment: It looks like the question was originally about a char[] and someone changed it to String, but they didn't remove every reference to "array"

Comment: Please, have a look at **Radix Sort** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort

Comment: Yes, `String` is immutable, but `StringBuilder`, `StringBuffer`, `char[]` are not

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that there are only 256 characters. Create a hash map for the 256 characters. Since the number 256 is known, it still counted as constant space. Just perform a linear time traversal and you'll get the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

"Constant extra space" means that you use the same amount of extra space, regardless of the size of the input string.

Here's how you do it:

1. Create an empty array of 256 integers, initialized to all 0.
2. For each character in the string, convert the character to an integer and increment the corresponding value in the array.
3. After you've done that for all characters, go through the array and output the characters that appeared.

In pseudo code it looks like this:

```
counts = array[256] of int, initialized to 0
// count character occurrences
for each char in string
    index = (int)char
    counts[index] = counts[index + 1]

// build string
outputString = ""
for index = 0 to 255
    if (counts[index] > 0)
        c = (char)index
        outputString = outputString + repeat(c, counts[index])

return outputString;
```